# Get only the current map from GMapping

Tags: navigation, mapping, occupancy-grid, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new in ROS and I want to do a DATMO application with laser scan.
For the first step of this application, I only need to get the current map created by GMapping. Is that possible?

Could you please tell me what should I do in details? or show me some references?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205638/get-only-the-current-map-from-gmapping/) by [sadek](https://answers.ros.org/users/21940/sadek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Sadek,

gmapping is designed to work with odometry and laser scan data and you cannot use it if one of them is missing. If I understand you need to transform laser data in an occupancy grid (that is the same topic type of map published by gmapping): in that case some kind of [Costmap2D](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) is what you need. You should set up static_map to false, so no external map is required and only laser data will be used, and rolling_window to true, so the robot will be every posed at centre of costmap. Costmap2D will publish */grid* that should be exactly what you need.

Unfortunately (for you) the Costmap2D is not provided as node since it is embedded in move_base node so you should get the sources and write your own node. Furthermore it do something more than transform laser data to occupancy grid: it define costs used for path planning: maybe you can find a setup that works fine for your goal.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sadek](https://answers.ros.org/users/21940/sadek/) on 2015-03-23**:
Thank you for your response. It's exactly what I need. However, is there any other package (more simpler) which converts laser data in an occupancy grid?

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2015-03-23**:
Not in my knowledge, sorry!

**Comment by [sadek](https://answers.ros.org/users/21940/sadek/) on 2015-03-23**:
Thanks afranceson. I'll try  Costmap2D then.